# « Menaces with spikes of » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

> *This is a native aluminum earring. All craftsmanship is of the highest
>   quality. It is studded with bismuth bronze and decorated with water
>   buffalo leather. [This object is adorned with hanging rings of red
>   zircon and dragon bone and **menaces with spikes of** red zircon, cow
>   leather and clear glass.] On the item is an image of two trillion cut
>   gems in native aluminum.*
>
> Adek Arek *"The Sides of Church"* : boucle d'oreille en alu. : 177 600 ; exposée ds. la salle à manger

[*Cet objet est orné d'anneaux en zircon rouge et en os de dragon, et [**menace** ?] de pointes de zircon rouge, de cuir de vache, et de verre translucide.*] Cette description d'un objet particulièrement légendaire provient d'un *rogue-like*<sup>1</sup>. On notera que ce ne sont pas les anneaux qui menaceraient, mais bien l'objet avec ses pointes (matériaux différents anneaux/pointes).

---

Ce n'est pas que la boucle d'oreille [menace](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/menace) dans le sens de constituer un danger, et elle ne menace pas de tomber en contexte. Dire qu'elle est [menaçante](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mena%C3%A7ant/50413?q=mena%C3%A7ante#50304) me semble maladroit. De plus, on a *avec* et un complément : les [*pointe*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pointe/1) de, comme par exemple la *pointe de/en diamant* (verre, gravure, joaillerie), *montée sur* un truc etc.

Sans doute une mauvaise piste car le sens anglais<sup>2</sup> est vraiment basé sur l'idée de *menaçant*. On a la forme intransitive, signifiant *to utter menaces/to be threatening*. On a une forme où j'ai identifié un exemple avec la préposition *with* mais c'est transitif (contrairement à notre exemple) : *to hold out as a punishment, penalty, or danger ; to threaten to inflict.* (au [*NED*](https://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/333/mode/1up), 3b trans. with inf. or object clause, i.e. Quarles Jonah C 1 b *Great Ashur minaces **with** whip in hand, **To** entertaine thee (welcome) to his land.*). Ça ressemble à [*menacer de*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/menacer) quelque chose (intrans., avec inf. ou subst.), mais la boucle d'oreille ne menace pas de *piquer* dans le sens usuel...

---

- Comment rend-on usuellement *menaces with spikes of* ici ? Est-ce avec une locution construite avec un verbe, un adjectif, un nom ? La boucle d'oreille *menace-t-elle vraiment **de** pointes de* zircon rouge ?

  - Peut-on rendre à la fois l'impression que donne l'objet et sa structure physique (et celle de ses pointes) ici ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>*Slaves to Armok: God of Blood Chapter II: [Dwarf Fortress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_Fortress)*. Les descriptions des objets sont générées de manière partiellement procédurale selon l'évènementiel de la partie et reflètent donc la diversité matérielle des lieux et les choix artistiques en ce qui a trait à la confection. J'ai miné ces roches, fait du verre, forgé du métal, taillé des pierres précieuses, tué des [monstres](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238598/megabeast-totem-crafting-and-displaying-specifics), des buffles dans les alentours de la forteresse, eu un cheptel, et plus ou moins agencé le tout de la confection jusqu'à la mise en scène etc.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> En explorant le sens du verbe en contexte sur *ELL*, [on m'explique](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/78734) que les *pointes* « *give it a menacing air* ».</sub>

Comment: As written in English, I think it’s a very effective description aimed at the same consumer who would purchase a menacing spiked collar for their Chihuahua in hopes of rendering, perhaps jokingly, the dog itself more menacing. Therefore, I think the verb “menaces” refers to whole the earring being/appearing menacing (and by extension to the person who would dare to wear it) to those who see it being worn (not to its wearer). Perhaps “menacing” should be in quotes & not be taken literally, but then again people who adorn their pets and selves with spikes are not after the “cute puppy-dog” look.

Comment: Also, as I read the English text, the earring has [menacing] spikes made of **three** materials: red zircon, cow leather, and clear glass (and not just the mineral red zircon); and therefore perhaps “épis” or “épines” would be a better, or at least more menacing, translation of “spikes” than “pointes.”

Comment: Est-ce que le verbe "to menace" est employé de cette manière ailleurs que dans le jeu Dwarf Fortress (d'où la citation est extraite, ce serait bien de le préciser)? J'ai des doutes... Je pense que l'auteur du jeu a simplement inventé cet usage du mot. Difficile de dire comment on traduit habituellement cette locution du coup.

Comment: [« Visuel »](http://imgur.com/u8fwU7e) de l'objet, au besoin...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Comment rend-on usuellement *menaces with spikes of* ici ? Est-ce avec une locution construite avec un verbe, un adjectif, un nom ? La boucle d'oreille *menace-t-elle vraiment* de *pointes de* zircon rouge ?

« *To menace* » est effectivement habituellement traduit par « menacer », mais c'est réellement l'action qui est décrite. Ici, il paraît effectivement maladroit de dire que c'est la boucle d'oreille qui est menaçante. On pourrait commencer par se concentrer sur les pointes.

> Cet objet est orné d'anneaux en zircon rouge et en os de dragon, et **de pointes menaçantes** de zircon rouge, de cuir de vache et de verre translucide.

On peut ensuite discuter sur le choix du mot. On souhaite ici rendre compte de leur aspect, de leur forme, de l'impression que l'objet, que les pointes donnent. Peut-être existe-t-il un [synonyme](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-synonymes/mena%C3%A7ant) plus approprié ou plus expressif pour un francophone. Par exemple :

> Cet objet est orné d'anneaux en zircon rouge et en os de dragon, et **d'agressives pointes** de zircon rouge, de cuir de vache et de verre translucide.

Comme souvent, une traduction mot à mot semble difficile.

#### Peut-on rendre à la fois l'impression que donne l'objet et sa structure physique (et celle de ses pointes) ici ?

Cela me semble effectivement possible.

On trouve souvent la locution « aspect menaçant<sup>1</sup> » pour décrire quelque chose qui génère une inquiétude sans proférer de véritables menaces. Des exemples bateau donneraient quelque chose du type : « Malgré l'aspect menaçant du ciel, il n'a pas plu de la journée. »

En construisant sur base de ma dernière proposition, on pourrait jouer utiliser cette locution avec quelque chose du type :

> Cet objet est orné d'anneaux en zircon rouge et en os de dragon, et **de (agressives) pointes** de zircon rouge, de cuir de vache et de verre translucide, **conférant à l'ensemble un aspect menaçant**.

---

<sub>1. Oui, ça manque de source. Je n'en ai pas trouvé pour certifier la validité et l'usage de cette locution. Compléments bienvenus.</sub>

Comment: « Aspect menaçant » est une traduction acceptable de « _menacing air_ ». :)

Answer (score 4):

Je proposerais la traduction suivante :

> Cet objet est orné d'anneaux en zircon rouge et en os de dragon, et
>   **de pointes de zircon rouge menaçantes**, de cuir de vache, et de verre
>   translucide.

Il serait plus habile de passer le verbe *menacer* en adjectif pour cette traduction.

A mon sens, ce sont bien les piques qui "menacent", qui sont menaçant, qui ont l'air menaçant et non pas directement la boucle d'oreille.

Il ne faut pas prendre ici *menaces with* pour *la boucle d'oreille menace avec ses pointes* qui pourrait être interpréter comme un danger potentiel (des boucles d'oreille dangereuses à porter) mais plutôt comme *la boucle d'oreille est ornée de pointes menaçantes* les pointes on l'air menaçantes mais on comprend bien que la boucle d'oreille n'est pas un danger.

Par exemple *The dark sky menaces with black clouds* peut être traduit par *Le ciel sombre menace de ses nuages noirs* sans ambiguïté car on comprends bien que *Le ciel est emplie de nuages noirs menaçants*.

Ou encore *L'armée menace avec ses soldats sur-équipés* et *L'armée composée de menaçants soldats sur-équipés*.

### Conclusion

Le fait de déplacer le verbe (dont la boucle d'oreille est actrice) en adjectif (qui qualifie les piques) conserve le sens de la phrase mais modifie le "porteur de l'information". C'est un mal nécessaire dans ce contexte si l'on veut que le lecteur comprenne que la boucle d'oreille n'est pas dangereuse.

Comment: Dans ce cas, j'ai l'impression que "menaces with" se rapportent à la fois aux pointes, au cuir et au verre. Autant les pointes, je comprends que ça puisse être menaçant, autant le cuir de vache, j'ai plus de mal. Êtes-vous sûr qu'il n'y a pas ici un sens technique de ce verbe, purement lié à la joaillerie ?

Comment: C'est vrai que *mences with* à l'air de se rapporter aux 3 éléments qui le suivent.
Cependant malgré mes recherches je n'ai pas trouvé d'exemple rapportant le verbe *to menace* à la joaillerie.

Answer (score 1):

C'est simplement l'emploi d'une figure de style, la [« personnification »](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/figures-de-style/personnification.php).  On a fait d'un être inanimé un personnage réel. Dans ce contexte c'est exactement l'objet (la boucle d'oreille) qui nous menace.

D'après moi, on peut dire:

*Cet objet est orné d'anneaux en zircon rouge et en os de dragon, et **il nous menace avec** des pointes de zircon rouge, de cuir de vache, et de verre translucide.*

Answer (score 1):

J'aime bien *en imposer* dans le sens d' « [i]nspirer l'admiration, le respect, parfois la crainte. »([*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/imposer)), ou « impressionner (quelqu'un), forcer le respect, l'admiration : Il veut nous en imposer avec ses manières. » ([*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/imposer/41960/locution?q=imposer#156580)), avec la préposition [*avec*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/avec/7023) (la cause, le moyen, la manière, le fait d'être muni de etc.). Peut-être moins intense que *menaçant*. Avec un choix de pronom, ici le possessif, et avec [*en*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/en/29043?q=en#28919) pour la composition afin d'éviter toute ambiguïté sur le rattachement des trois matériaux aux pointes. Enfin, j'aime bien les [*pics*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pic/1) (*extrémités* par métonymie) :

> Cet objet est orné d'anneaux en zircon rouge et en os de dragon, et en
>   impose avec ses pics en zircon rouge, en cuir de vache, et en verre
>   translucide.

En aval de la menace, [*faire peur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peur), dans le sens non actif de *faire peur à voir*. Ici l'objet *fait peur* (à voir) *avec ses pics en zircon* etc : une forme d'exagération.